# Java plugin "There is no site selected" Any idea on this?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

trying to install checkstyle from : http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/downloads.html
when I click help->install software then add checkstyle link
I got :There is no site selected

so next button is grayed, any idea ?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server by any chance?

Comment: are you aware of existence of this site called google? http://www.google.com is the address!!!

Comment: yes of course!what is the difference ?

Comment: What I meant is that instead of asking what a proxy server is here, you could have (and should have) looked it up, it's a very basic concept that you will need to know about! So... are you behind one or not?

Comment: yes I'm , this could resolve my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have eclipse here right now, but from memory you will need to specify the proxy server details in eclipse so that it can go past it. See [this](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t45492.html) or [this](http://www.drgarbage.com/eclipse-proxy-configuration-guide.html)

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the page at http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/downloads.html?

The site URL is http://eclipse-cs.sf.net/update/

Comment: yes, I click add then add name"checkstyle" and the link :http://eclipse-cs.sf.net/update/